# Solidity minting NFT images not in the sequence from first to last one

Tags: solidity, contract, nft

I have my contract in solidity for my NFT collection. Usually people are minting from contract from first to last piece. Is it possible that they will mint only one exact piece? I mean something like reservation. Can I store this reservation list somewhere for example it will be address and number of image:

```
"0x62e4613BBA89f81F8ea6f286eC4c3d7e6896509e": 4
```

so user with address `0x62e4613BBA82f81F8ea6f686eC4c3d7e6896509e` will be minting 4th element of the collection. He cannot mint any other but he can mint whenever he wants. Is it even possible? Can I pass any argument to `mint` method that will mint exact piece from whole collection?

Answer (score 0):

well, is technically possible, maybe with some mappings, requires and that, but maybe will be more hard to know exactly how much nft have been minted or what nft have already been minted, but you can have a mapping of address to an array of uint where the address is the user address and in the array of uint will be the tokenId that are reserved to that address, and another mapping of uint to addres, where the uint is the token id and the address is the user address and you can use it to know if that token id is already reserved or minted